# what is the difference between undecimated and decimated wavelet transform

Tags: image-processing, wavelet, wavelet-transform

Can anyone simply explain what is the difference between undecimated and decimated wavelet transform? what are the similarities and differences? how are they different?

Answer (score -1):

Decimated is the regular wavelet transform, it works by downsampling our signal, reducing the number of coefficients. 64 coefficients may become 32, 16, and so on.

Undecimated wavelet transform is the opposite, it works by upsampling our signal, augmenting the number of coefficients. 64 coefficients may become 128, 256, and so on.